# Find element with attribute with value starting with an integer in capybara selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, capybara

I was trying to locate an element with attribute whose value is starting with an integer.

```
<div data-id=2009ac> ... </div>
```

And whine I use css locator, as below, to locate the element

```
page.find("div[data-id=2009ac]")
```

I'm getting exception stating that element not found or invalid locator

How to locate such elements?

Answer (score 0):

we need to enclose the attribute values with quotes for it to work when it starts with integer

```
page.find("div[data-id='2009ac']")
```

The same wouldn't work for attributes like id and class. And for attribute values that doesn't start with integer we can simple use without enclosing with quotes. For example

```
 <div data-id=a2009ac> ... </div>
```

To locate the above element we can use

```
page.find("div[data-id=a2009ac]")
```